# Missing value introduced in a logical

Tags: r, logic

I was working with the inbuilt data set (`ggplot2`), named `diamonds`. After having assigned to `dia1`, I performed the following script, so as to group the values according to their carats. I got a message regarding `NAs` being introduced by coercion. I fail to understand how that would have happened, as is also apparent by the sum of the `is.na()` vector equating to zero.

```
#data
library(ggplot2)
dia1 <- diamonds

#logic
x<-1
dia1$carat<-as.character(dia1$carat)
for (i in 1:(length(dia1$carat))){

if (0<(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))&(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))<=1){
  dia1$carat[x]<-"0-1"
}
if (1 < (as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))&(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x])) <= 2){
  dia1$carat[x]<-"1-2"
}
if (2<(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))&(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))<=3){
  dia1$carat[x]<-"2-3"
}
if (3<(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))&(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))<=4){
  dia1$carat[x]<-"3-4"
}
if (4<(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))&(as.numeric(dia1$carat[x]))<=5){
  dia1$carat[x]<-"4-5"
}
  x<-x+1
}
```

> Error in if (0 < (as.numeric(dia1$carat[x])) &
>   (as.numeric(dia1$carat[x])) <  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: NAs introduced by coercion 
>   2: NAs introduced by coercion

```
# check if there are any NAs in the data
sum(is.na(dia1$carat))
[1] 0
```

Alternatively, why were there no `NAs` introduced when the `dia1$carat` vector was explicitly coerced to a character, but there were `NAs` introduced in the back transformation?

Comment: `cut(dia$carat, breaks=0:6, labels=c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5", "5-6"), include.lowest=TRUE)` will probably be a great deal more efficient. And, you should probably do a `range(dia$carat)` to validate your assumptions.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks. Will use. But as a learning objective, I wanted to know what went wrong with my code.

Comment: As I said, you might want to do a `range(dia$carat)` to validate your assumptions. And `for` + `if` == python/C/Java, not R.

Comment: It is 0.2, 5.01. Before coercing the vector to character, that is.

Comment: @hrbrmstr What would then be the equivalent of for+if in R, in case there is no function (like cut here) to do the operation?

Comment: (a) what assumptions is your code making that the values you get from `range` telling you are invalid? (b) list operations like `lapply`, `sapply`, `vapply` or the new idioms from the `purrr` pkg. (c) why would you take a numeric field, convert it to character, only to convert it back to numeric over and over and over again?

Comment: @hrbrmstr (B), okay, will take into consideration. (C) no reason, but if I were to out of curiosity, why would it create a problem? (A) I have no clue! Sorry to be slow. At level 0 currently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is we are supplying *NA* to `if()`, try this example:

```
if(NA > 1){1} else {2}
```

> Error in if (NA > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

In your case, if we consider 1st row *carat* is `"0.23"`, first `if()` statement is evaluating it correctly after converting it to number, then if within range assigning a new value of `"0-1"`. Then second `if()` is trying to convert `"0-1"` to numeric, so we are getting `NA`.

Other advice about the code:

- Just use `cut()`
- Use `if(){...} else if(){...} ...`
- I don't get why we have `x` variable, we could use `i` instead.
- Read about `seq_along()`, `summary()`, `str()`
- Use temporary variable for `as.numeric(dia1$carat[x])`
- Use whitespaces